# Editing HTML5 LocalStorage through a function

Tags: json, local-storage

I want to be able to add an "Ignore List" with the results being saved on the users browser.

The Ignored List is saved as a JSON array and looks like this:

```
[{"username":"test_user","date_added":"19/08/13","description":"Don't like this person."},{"username":"test_user_2","date_added":"19/08/13","description":"Don't like this person."}]
```

And the function required to add the users look like this:

```
function add_to_ignore_list()
{
    var ignored_users = localStorage.getItem("ignore_list"); // returns ignore list
    var username = return_current_username(); // returns test_user3
    var date = return_current_date(); // returns 19/08/13
    var description = prompt("Why do you want to ignore this user?"); // returns desc

    add_to_list = {
        "username" : username,
        "date_added" : date, 
        "description" : description
    };
    ignored_users.push(add_to_list);
    localStorage["ignore_list"] = JSON.stringify(ignored_users);
    $(".user_wrapper").css("background-color","#B40404");
}
```

For some reason it isn't working and I can't see why Please help.

Comment: Is your ignore_list already stored in localStorage or is this the first time?  Do you see any errors in the console? And lastly - what browser + version are you testing with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ignored_users is stored as a string.

When you retrieve it from localStorage, you need to parse it before you use it.

change:

```
var ignored_users = localStorage.getItem("ignore_list");
```

to (assumes it had previously been stored):

```
var ignored_users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("ignore_list"));
```

Comment: That was exactly it:)